# when echoing information about a mysql table as a link, and sending information with the link to be retrieved in another page using $_GET not working

Tags: php, mysql

In my mysql table I have the primary key column as "id", I want to echo the name of the album (stored as "titre" in mysql) as a link, and in the link include the id number, so the user can access all the information about the album in the link page and modify it. So I know it should look something like this to echo a link and include the id which I retrieved already from mysql:

```
echo <a href='$link&id=$id'>Link</a>
```

but can't figure out the correct way of writing it so that &id isn't either disregarded or sent as part of the string.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
    $requete='SELECT titre, id FROM AY_albums';
    $response = $bdd->query($requete);
    while($donnees = $response->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $p = "Nom :".$donnees['titre']." <br />\n";
        $idIci=$donnees['id'];
        $lien="modifierAlbumAdmin.php";

        echo "<a href='$lien'&id=$idIci>$p</a>";
    } ?>
```

And this is the code I have to retrieve it on the page the link leads to:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["id"])){
        $requete ='SELECT * FROM AY_albums WHERE id=$_GET["id"]';
        $response = $bdd->query($requete);
        $donnees = $response->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $titre=$donnees['titre'];
        print "yes";
    }
?>
```

I added a print statement to see if it enters the if statement and it doesn't even enter. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't be `echo "<a href='$lien?id=$idIci'>$p</a>";` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is not correct

```
 $requete ='SELECT * FROM AY_albums WHERE id=$_GET["id"]';
```

Single quote forces everything to be string and won't parse string

```
Use
 $requete ='SELECT * FROM AY_albums WHERE id='.$_GET["id"];
```

Use 
    echo "< a href='".$lien."?id=$idIci'>$p";

Query string is getting attached to file name. Both should be separated by ?(question mark)

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately! Still getting the blank result on the next page.

Comment: Andrew sorry I found one more issue. Check now ... I have updated the answer.

Comment: Welcome Andrew but remember the difference between single quote n double quote :)